# Select SQL Query to get xml node values from ntext column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I want to get one xml node value from NTEXT column which contains xml based on where clause quering on another xml node value. 
**RDBMS Type: Microsoft SQL Server T-SQL**
Here: I want to get Code node value based on StoreId where clause value. How do I get it?
Input: 100
Output:ABCDE

For example:

```
<root>
  <StoreProfile>
    <General>
     <StoreId>100</StoreId>
     <Code>ABCDE</Code>
    </General>
  </StoreProfile>
</root>
```

Comment: What dbms are you using.  Some sql dialects have specific xml primitives.

Comment: Define the database that you are working with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or 2008 you can use XQuery like so:

For more on XQuery see [XQuery Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx)

```
DECLARE @storeId INT
SET @storeId = 100

CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(
    xmlColumn NTEXT
)

INSERT INTO #TestTable (xmlColumn) Values('<root><StoreProfile><General><StoreId>100</StoreId><Code>ABCDE</Code></General></StoreProfile></root>')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (xmlColumn) Values('<root><StoreProfile><General><StoreId>200</StoreId><Code>FGHIJ</Code></General></StoreProfile></root>')

SELECT 
    StoreProfile.value('Code[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as Code 
FROM #TestTable
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(xmlColumn AS XML)) AS A(B) 
    CROSS APPLY A.B.nodes('//root/StoreProfile/General[StoreId = sql:variable("@storeId")]') AS StoreProfiles(StoreProfile)

DROP TABLE #TestTable
```